# altered and garbled message when using sink function

Tags: r, sink

for some reason, all of the sudden, whenever i use sink function to save the console output into txt file, I start getting a weird tibble output, for example:

[3m[38;5;246m[39m[23m  [3m[38;5;246m[39m[23m     [3m[38;5;246m[39m[23m   [3m[38;5;246m[39m[23m [3m[38;5;246m[39m[23m
[38;5;250m1[39m FALSE  [4m1[24m[4m0[24m930      5.52    5.16     0
[38;5;250m2[39m TRUE    [4m1[24m547      9.44   10.4      0

can you please, please please help.. I tried everything from reinstalling r and rstudio, updating all packages including tidyverse and tibble, downgrading packages, etc etc etc.. i also tried all options from this github forum: https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/396

can you experts please help.. thanks

Comment: Please provide a sample of your tibble along with the code that you used for the `sink` function.  Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: This seems to be a bug in tibble (https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/396). Try converting the tibble to a data frame before printing.